How to get active cell address using graph api in java sdk
I want to retrieve the address of the active cell in the worksheet. The active cell address is the last modified cell in the sheet where the cell cursor is currently located.
For example, in the below sheet the active cell address is : C2


I'm afraid that Graph API itself doesn't expose any endpoint to get active cell, the same for active worksheet.
